# Conditional Search in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that updates hourly. Sometimes it might miss an hour for whatever reason. I want to count records at 4AM everyday and if there is no record, look at the next hour (5AM). I also want it to return 0 if neither record exists.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(last_update) as dt,
    COUNT(DISTINCT "number") as redlit
FROM mytable
WHERE 
    status = 'foo' AND 
    defective = 'yes' AND
    last_update >= '2020-01-01' AND
CASE WHEN (DATE_PART('hour',last_update) = 4) IS NULL THEN (DATE_PART('hour',last_update) = 5)
ELSE (DATE_PART('hour',last_update) = 4) END
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY dt;
```

The `CASE WHEN` statement seems to only look at 4AM. I'm not sure how to get it to look at 5AM in cases when 4AM does not exist. And I am not sure how to return 0 if both are `NULL`.

Sample:

```
dt       redlit datepart
2020-03-19  21  4.0
2020-03-20  14  4.0
2020-03-22  16  4.0
2020-03-23  45  4.0
```

Desired Result:

```
dt       redlit datepart
2020-03-19  21  4.0
2020-03-20  14  4.0
2020-03-21  20  5.0
2020-03-22  16  4.0
2020-03-23  45  4.0
2020-03-24  0   NULL
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added. Right now, the datepart returned is always 4 and it omits 2020-03-21 because that hour doesn't exist in my table. But hour 5 does exist and i want that to be returned when hour 4 is not present and if niether exists, then return 0 as shown in 2020-03-24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much familiar with the syntax of redshift, neither i have a way to test this code. But this should work. This code is not elegant, and may need a bit of tweaking

```
Select m.dt,
    Case When dp = 4 then m4.redlit 
        When  dp = 5 then m5.redlit
        Else 0 End as  redlit
 from
(
    SELECT 
        DATE(last_update) as dt,
        0 as dp,
        COUNT(DISTINCT "number") as redlit
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        status = 'foo' AND dt
        defective = 'yes' AND
        last_update >= '2020-01-01' AND
    GROUP BY 1,2
) m
left join
(
    SELECT 
        DATE(last_update) as dt,
        4 as dp,
        COUNT(DISTINCT "number") as redlit
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        status = 'foo' AND 
        defective = 'yes' AND
        last_update >= '2020-01-01' AND
        DATE_PART('hour',last_update) = 4
    GROUP BY 1,2
) m4 on m.dt = m4.dt 
left join
(
    SELECT 
        DATE(last_update) as dt,
        5 as dp,
        COUNT(DISTINCT "number") as redlit
    FROM mytable
    WHERE 
        status = 'foo' AND 
        defective = 'yes' AND
        last_update >= '2020-01-01' AND
        DATE_PART('hour',last_update) = 4
    GROUP BY 1,2
) m5 on m.dt = m5.dt
```